# Swift URLComponents not converting empty spaces correctly

Tags: swift, urlsession

I have a very simple GET Request in Swift 4 using `URLSession` for the `dataTask` and the `URLComponents` to create the URL/String.

The problem I have is as shown in the code snippet below

```swift
var url = URLComponents(string: "http://myServer.com:8086/query")
url?.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "db", value: "Database"),
            URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: ("SELECT valueOne,valueTwo FROM \"TABLE\" WHERE \"valueOne\"='\(currValue)' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1"))
            ]
NSLog((url?.url?.absoluteString)!)

/* 
   NSLog: http://myServer.com:8086/query?db=Database&q=SELECT2alueOne,valueTwo
   0.000000ROM222TABLE220WHERE222valueOne23D'currValue'                   
   0RDER2Y      0me      -8ESC2MIT2 
*/
```

I tried building the `URL` directly and applying the `addingPercentEncoding` with `urlQueryAllowed` on the query part of the string but I still got the same result. The only thing that partially worked was to substitute the empty spaces in the query with "+", but there was still a problem with the escaped inverted comas.
I'm quite new to Swift so my assumption is I'm missing something very obvious. Any and all assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming `currValue = 1`, your URL works out to `http://myServer.com:8086/query?db=Database&q=SELECT%20valueOne,valueTwo%20FROM%20%22TABLE%22%20WHERE%20%22valueOne%22%3D'1'%20ORDER%20BY%20time%20DESC%20LIMIT%201`, which looks correct to me. A bigger concern is SQL Injection attack if you build your URL this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is that `NSLog` does not print out percent Escaped strings correctly, `print` on the other hand does. The best thing would have been just to set a breakpoint on the `NSLog` line and check the url value if it is correct, which it was.

Answer (score 0):

**I have created this function to generate URL. You can use this function to create your URL with safe ASCII characters.**

```
func urlGenretor() -> URL{
    var components = URLComponents()
    components.scheme = "https"
    components.host = "myServer.com:8086"
    components.path = "/query"
    let database = URLQueryItem(name: "db", value: "Database")
    let queryItem2 = URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: ("SELECT valueOne,valueTwo FROM \"TABLE\" WHERE \"valueOne\"='\(currValue)' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1"))
    components.queryItems = [database,queryItem2]
    let url = components.url
    print(url!)
    return url!
```